# Errors coming from UE5 source files even in new project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I have these errors from files that I have not made any changed to.

- I have tried regenerating Visual Studio files.
- I also uninstalled/reinstalled Unreal engine and Visual Studio.
- I originally started with Visual Studio 2019 but when I started getting these issues, I did update to Visual Studio 2022.
- One post I found said the issue was resolved by going to the Visual Studio Installer → Visual Study Community 2022 → Modify - Individual Components → uncheck IDE Support for Unreal Engine. but this did not resolve it for me
- Another post suggested Click Edit → Editor Preferences → Source Code
  Change Source Code Editor to “Visual Studio 2022”
  Click Tools → Refresh Visual Studio 2022 Project
  Click Tools → Open Visual Studio 2022 to open the project in Visual Studio
- I have tried opening various UE5 projects but the errors persist even when no code/classes have been added.

I'm lost in this dark world any help is appreciated!

Output:

```
[2023.01.15-23.40.10:775][  0]LogShaderCompilers: Display: Autogen file is unchanged, skipping write.
[2023.01.15-23.40.11:312][  0]LogAudio: Display: Registering Engine Module Parameter Interfaces...
[2023.01.15-23.40.12:303][  0]LogAudioCaptureCore: Display: No Audio Capture implementations found. Audio input will be silent.
[2023.01.15-23.40.12:304][  0]LogAudioCaptureCore: Display: No Audio Capture implementations found. Audio input will be silent.
[2023.01.15-23.40.12:615][  0]LogInit: Error: VisualStudioToolsCommandlet looked like a commandlet, but we could not find the class.
Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Some of Error List:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1835   attribute "deprecated" does not apply here  MyProject   C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\Serialization\BulkData.h    283 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1835   attribute "deprecated" does not apply here  MyProject   C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\Serialization\BulkData.h    1239    
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  MyProject   C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   381 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "FRHIViewableResource" is undefined  MyProject   C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\RHI\Public\RHI.h   2233
```

[image: Error List]

Comment: Does recompiling the engine itself give you an error?

Comment: It does not. I am able to compile in Unreal and run the game :/

Comment: Have you viewed [this thread](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/error-visualstudiotoolscommandlet-looked-like-a-commandlet-but-we-could-not-find-the-class/716163/5) and tried the solutions?

Comment: I did. Unfortunately unchecking IDE support for unreal engine in visual studio installer did not fix the issue

Comment: If you can build the game and engine, everything is working as intended. IntelliSense tends to fail a lot with UE and it is usually best to set the Error list to "Build" instead of "Build + IntelliSense" and ignore IntelliSense warnings alltogether.

Comment: Ok, this did seem to resolve the issue. If you want to post this as an answer @MaxPlay I will mark as resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from a comment I gave to the original question:

The "Error List" window in Visual Studio does not work well with Unreal, due to parsing issues of IntelliSense. The best way to see if an Unreal project builds seems to be to just build it and ignore IntelliSense alltogether. In this case, it is best to set the dropdown in the "Error List" window to "Build" instead of "Build + IntelliSense", to filter out any errors that just come from IntelliSense.

I found to just ignore the "Error List" and just work with the "Output" window to be a good solution as well, but that's just preference.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a "Plugins" directory in my project. There I copied the plugin and deleted the directories Binaries and Intermediate in the plugin. Started the project and recompiled the plugin. Closed the project and right clicked on the .uproject file and selected Generate Visual ..... The error is now gone.