# FPointDamageEvent error "incomplete type is not allowed" (Unreal Engine 5.1)

Tags: c++17, unreal-engine5

The instructor in the C++ course I'm following used this code here, and I copied it exactly:[Code the course instructor used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23JU8.png)

But I get this error. Not sure what to do. I know that the instructor is doing this in 4.27 and I'm doing it in 5.1. Did something change between those two versions that may have caused this error? How to I get around it?
[The error I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb4nT.png)

Here's my whole function for reference:
[Whole function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsu8A.png)

Comment: You are likely just missing an include. Have you tried including the header in which the type is defined? Also, if this is just IntelliSense and not a build error, ignore it and [refer to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75129268/errors-coming-from-ue5-source-files-even-in-new-project/75136624#75136624).

Answer (score 1):

For UE5.1 you need to write this in your file

```
#include "Engine/DamageEvents.h"
```