# VisualStudio2019 and Unreal, I cant solve the errors

Tags: c#, unreal-engine4

I want to send HTTP requests and I use a flask server and Unreal code to manipulate a real life NAO robot. I have errors in these lines of code and I cant seem to understand the exact problem.

Here is the code snippets that get the error:

```
UCLASS(ClassGroup = (Custom), meta = (BlueprintSpawnableComponent))
class INTERNSHIPUNREAL_API URobotArmControllerComponent : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
```

Here is the error>

Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier InternshipUnreal    C:\Users\Simal\Documents\Unreal Projects\InternshipUnreal\Source\InternshipUnreal\Public\RobotArmController.h   17

```
void URobotArmControllerComponent::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    // Call the MoveArm function with the new position
    MoveArm(GetOwner()->GetActorLocation().Y);
}
```

Here is the error>

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0135   class "UObject" has no member "TickComponent"   InternshipUnreal    C:\Users\Simal\Documents\Unreal Projects\InternshipUnreal\Source\InternshipUnreal\Public\RobotArmController.cpp 14

Comment: Are those Intellisense errors? If yes, you can completely ignore them. Intellisense breaks easily around UE's macros. Make sure to only look at the compilation output.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75129268/errors-coming-from-ue5-source-files-even-in-new-project/75136624#75136624) might help you.

Comment: yeap, when  I tried compiling in Unreal it said compile failed but after a few times it compiled succesfully. Don’t know what it is the cause exactly but it is solved. Thanks!